# Hibernate mapping and merging

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes like this :

Message(id, title, content)

MessageEmployee(id, messageId, employeeId, readFlag)

and 2 tables like this :

MESSAGE(mess_id, mess_title, mess_content)

MESSAGE_EMPLOYEE(mess_empl_id, mess_id, empl_id, read_fg)

Mapping files :

```
    <hibernate-mapping package="core">
        <class name="Message" table="MESSAGE">
            <!-- class id -->
            <id name="id" type="int" column="MESS_ID" length="11">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>

            <property name="content" type="string" column="MESS_CONTENT" />
            <property name="title" type="string" column="MESS_TITLE" /> 
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>


    <hibernate-mapping package="core">
        <class name="MessageEmployee" table="MESSAGE_EMPLOYEE">
            <!-- class id -->
            <id name="id" type="int" column="MESS_EMPL_ID" length="11">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>

            <!-- employee -->
            <many-to-one name="employee" class="core.Employee"
                column="EMPL_ID" cascade="save-update,merge" lazy="false" />

            <!-- message -->
            <many-to-one name="message" class="core.Message"
                column="MESS_ID" cascade="save-update,merge" lazy="false" />

            <property name="readFlag" type="character" column="READ_FG" />      
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my problem :
let's say I already have a message in database, and I want to create a messageEmployee and save it.

Code snippet :

```
    Message sent = new Message(content, title);
    Employee e = employeeDao.loadEmployeeWithId(Integer.valueOf(to));

    messageDao.merge(sent)

    MessageEmployee m = new MessageEmployee(sent, e, null);
    m.setReadFlag('N');
    messageEmployeeDao.mergeMessageEmploye(m);
```

When I `merge(messageEmployee)`, it creates a new `message` and a new `messageEmployee` in database, but I don't want it to create a new `message`.

I'm quite sure my mapping is wrong since I am no expert, so what could I change to get the behaviour I want ?

Comment: Try using cascade="none" in many-to-one mapping of Message class.

Comment: Tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please give some code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create a new `Message` object because you are not providing `id` in your message object `sent`. When you execute `messageDao.merge(sent)`, the sent object doesn't have and `id` to merge with. It is pure transient object. Try loading it from database like Employee.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I just added `sent = messageDao.merge(sent);` to get an id.